# Why is my PC failing with three different types of BSOD?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have experienced three types of BSOD within one month.

- BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO
- Process1 initialization failed
- unmoutable_Boot_volume

Could this BSOD problem require installing a new OS? I am using Windows 7 Ultimate.

Could my **hard disk** be causing the problem, so I will need to replace it?

Could my **RAM** be causing the problem, so I will need to replace it?

Comment: As it stands, any answer could only be a guess. I expect this will be closed unless you provide a lot more information.

Comment: what information I  should provide, please tell @Xavierjazz

Comment: It is likely to be a failing component or broken driver, perhaps disk, and the timing related to activities like Windows Update.  First disable automatic reboot on system failure so you can see the BSOD: `Control Panel / System / Advanced system settings /Startup and Recovery /  Automatic restart` and untick.

Comment: @Paul Yes I untick the thing, what you said. Now what should I do?

Comment: @LathaSharmaji Unfortunately, wait for the next BSOD - it might provide clues.  There may be clues in the event logs too.

Comment: @Paul I understand Your words, i will wait for next BSOD error, But BSOD error at glowing screen means I cant able reach Welcome screen, How I can't able to view event logs?

Comment: There may be clues in the event logs before the next BSOD.  If there is a component erroring, it might log the event prior to the error becoming bad enough to BSOD.

Comment: sorry, I don't have enough reputation to chat, so Please don't move this words to chat.

Comment: What BSOD error(s) are you getting?

Comment: same question, new user, new name; http://superuser.com/questions/989232/why-is-my-pc-working-fine looks as mentioned there, your hard disk is dying. Get it replaced

Comment: @Sathya i am changing hard disk, but are you really sure? because they are so many components in PC example: RAM etc